# Excel 2013 won't open html based XLS file

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I click an HTML based Excel file, Excel runs but won't open the file. It won't ask if I want to open it or not, acts as I say NO.

I can open the same file on another PC as expected.

I've examined the trust setting of Excel but all of them are default (Prompt user)

File source: [file.xls at pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/wxcT4UGf)

What would be the reason here?

Comment: if the same file opens correctly on another pc with the same version of excel, then probably you need to repair your Excel installation.

Comment: Can you open other excel files on this pc?

Comment: I found the reason: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/the_microsoft_excel_support_team_blog/2015/08/19/blocked-access-to-files-with-windows-10/

Comment: Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer). You might want to convert your comment into an answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason: [blogs.technet.microsoft.com/](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/the_microsoft_excel_support_team_blog/2015/08/19/blocked-access-to-files-with-windows-10/)